# How to select A radio button from JAVATable

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I want to select a radio button from JAVA table.

1. 1st I tried to get hierarchy through object spy, but I got hierarchy up to JavaTable, it didn't show radio button

   `JavaDialog("").JavaTable("")`
2. Then I tried record and play but it didn't work.
   While playing back, QTP didn't select a radio button which was selected during recording.

How can I select A radio button from java table?  This table has 2 columns and 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to grab the JavaDialog("").JavaTable("").object and get the radio button children and use the native method  to select it.